# How to avoid Undertow Connection RESET in apache benchmark test?

Tags: nio, microservices, undertow, sysctl

### Using apache benchmarking 100K request 20K concurrent users:

```
   $ ab -n 100000 -c 20000 http://localhost:8080/mrs/ping
    Completed 10000 requests
    Completed 20000 requests
    Completed 30000 requests
    Completed 40000 requests
    Completed 50000 requests
    Completed 60000 requests
    Completed 70000 requests
    Completed 80000 requests
    Completed 90000 requests
    apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)  <<< HOW to overcome??
```

### Below is the Undertow (version 1.2.6 + xnio-api 3.3.1) PingServer:

```
public class UndertowPingServer {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UndertowPingServer.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException {

        PathHandler path = Handlers.path()
                .addPrefixPath("/mrs/ping", new HttpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(
                                Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Server Time:" + new Date().toString() + "\n\n");
                    }
                });
Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder()
   .setHandler(path)
   .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
   .setBufferSize(1024 * 16)
//this seems slightly faster in some configurations
  .setIoThreads(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2) 
                    .setSocketOption(Options.BACKLOG, 500000)
                    .setWorkerThreads(2000)
//don't send a keep-alive header for HTTP/1.1 requests, as it is not required
                    .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALWAYS_SET_KEEP_ALIVE, false); 
            Undertow server = builder.build();
            server.start();
            log.info("micro-service running!");
        }
    }
```

All the needed linux kernel sockets and thread settings via sysctl are already done. That is why it can do the first 90K request with 20k users without issue.

Comment: I suspect is xnio or undertow library giving me this issue.

Comment: Issue did NOT initially pops up in Jetty 9.x benchmarking. Therefore, I suspected Undertow at first.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `-r` parameter to ab to prevent it exitting.

from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html

> -r
>
> ```
> Don't exit on socket receive errors.
> ```

Connections will start to timeout and can prolong testing time by a timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

**I just FOUND OUT similar issue from:** 
blog.scene.ro/posts/apache-benchmark-apr_socket_recv

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=0
```

This did the job. NO MORE Connection reset by peer (104). 
Guess this might not be a undertow or xnio-api issue.

Comment: It is not a good idea to disable TCP Syn Cookies unless you're okay with getting downed by a DoS attack.

Answer (score 0):

**Another observation:**

```
Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder()
.setSocketOption(Options.BACKLOG, 100000) // << Does impact the REST
```

**and also MAY related to:**

```
$ sysctl -a | grep -i sync
...
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 100000
```